# Проблема с перестановкой replace() фрагментов в Android

Tags: android-fragment, android-viewpager, android, java, slider

Привет.

Пишу приложение на Android, в котором через меню заменяю один фрагмент на другой функцией replace(). Все было хорошо, пока в одном из фрагментов не стал использовать ViewPager, который содержит другие фрагменты. При первом вызове replace() все хорошо, а при последующих некоторые фрагменты в ViewPager пропадают, а некоторые появляются при пролистывании, а точнее, не для всех фрагментов в ViewPager выполняется getItem().

В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class GunStats extends Fragment {

    public GunStats() {
    }

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SlidingTabLayout mTab;

    private static Fragment fr1, fr2, fr3;

    static {
        fr1 = GunStats1.getFragment();
        fr2 = GunStats1.getFragment();
        fr3 = GunStats1.getFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_tabs, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTab = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTab.setViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String[] tabText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs_text);

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            Log.d("TAG", "Constructor");
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.d("TAG", "getItem");
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return fr1;
                case 1: return fr2;
                case 2: return fr3;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabText[position];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Встречался с этим не раз, но как решал - хз))) Попробуйте notifyDataSetChanged() над адаптером ViewPager-a вызывать после присвоения ему адаптера.

Comment: Также, возможно, такое происходит при отображении пайджера с нулевым фрагментом. В этом случае не вызывается onPageChangeListeneer() pager-a. Решается это получение сслыки на листенер и вызова чрез него 0-ого фрагмента.

Comment: Первый вариант не сработал. На счет второго - мне надо установить listener на ViewPager (setOnPaheChangeListener). Но как вызвать нулевой фрагмент и в каком месте вызывать?

Comment: @antoncti, по второму варианту я так делал: создавал отдельный класс - onPageChangeListener, присваивал его экземпляр в означенном выше вами методе. После вызывал pager.setCurrentItem(position). Далее проверял, position==0 и если да, то вызывал listener.onPageSelected(0);

Comment: Я только не понял: это все необходимо выполнять в getItem()?  Просто именно getItem не всегда выполняется у меня, или в onCreateView? А если в onCreateView, то как узнать значение position?

Comment: Выполнять надо там, где вы инициализируете pager и adapter к нему. А position можно в переменной какой-нить хранить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` используйте `getChildFragmentManager()`

Попробуйте ещё не держать фрагменты в статике, а каждый раз создавать новые в `getItem(int position)`

Comment: День добрый, возникла такая же проблема с пропажей фрагментов, воспользовался вашим советом с заменой на `getChildFragmentManager()` и все заработало. Но мне стало интересно почему? искал на просторах рунета, и нигде не объясняется чем отличаются `getChildFragmentManager()` от `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Можете объяснить, или где почитать об этом на русском